# VirtualBox installer hangs before any dialog, Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, installation

I am unable to (re)install VirtualBox, on Windows 10.

I had VirtualBox running fine, but then I'd attempted to install Docker, and that apparently screwed things up.

I uninstalled Docker, but VirtualBox wasn't starting, I uninstalled VirtualBox, but I'm unable to reinstall.

When I double click the 5.2.0, 5.0.040, or 5.1.30 installer - I get a pointed cursor with loading circle, and the file explorer window becomes unresponsive. There's no dialog.

Any suggestions for resolving?

I have checked that the VirtualBox drivers aren't there, [as per here](https://dottech.org/101997/how-to-uninstall-virtualbox-drivers-on-windows/).

Any suggestions? - My best other bet is reinstalling Windows from scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The installer hasn't hung.

It just takes ages to get started.

Let it wait for a good 20 minutes.